# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when adding and removing a view from different views

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access

I have created a game with a in game shop view and view controller.
The shop can be accessed in then menu (ViewController.m) and from the Game Over screen (GameViewController.m).

My problem is that if I have displayed the shop once in the menu, and then play a game and access the shop in the game over screen and try to buy something, the app crashes trowing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error without much info. (Breaking at

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:lPayment];
```

line in the ButtonPressed action in my ShopViewController when trying to buy a IAP.

My view are set up like this:

Menuview -> Ladderview -> Gameview -> ShopView

and

Menuview -> Shopview

Hope you can help me pinpoint the error,

**EDIT -----------**

It seems that I can reproduce the error from the menu -> Shopview without using the game view. I can do this by pressing a "buy button", pressing cancel, navigate back to the menu, go back to the shop, and repeat. On the 3-4th attempt it crashes at the same line. Here is the entire button pressed method:

```
- (void)buyButtonPressed:(UIButton *)pButton {
    NSInteger lTag = [pButton tag];
    //////NSLog(@"Button tag: %i"), lTag;

    Reachability *lReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus lCurrentNetworkStatus = [lReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (lCurrentNetworkStatus != NotReachable) {
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
            SKPayment *lPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[mPriceArray objectAtIndex:lTag]];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:lPayment];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

        } else {
            [self showAlertViewWithText:@"Purchases are disabled. Please check your settings for General -> Restrictions -> In-App Purchases and try again." andTitle:@"Warning"];
        }
    } else {
        [self showAlertViewWithText:@"No network connection!" andTitle:@"Warning"];
    }
}
```

So it might seem as the lPayment is being deallocated. I even tried to set

```
mProductIds = nil;
mPriceArray = nil;
```

when I remove the shop view, trying to force it to allocate it again when I reload the shop, but without any luck.

Thanks

Comment: Code please. at lease the line make it crash.

Comment: Hi xlc0212, I have updated the question. It crashed when referring to lPayment like carmin is pointing out. But don't know how to prevent that. Any ideas?

Comment: Discovered the hard way:  Clang does NOT warn when returning from a method which returns a value which does NOT reach a return statement.  The result of such a method will be garbage.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is a dangling pointer.  EXC_BAD_ACCESS is the CPU moaning that you are addressing non-existent memory or memory which is outside of your access rights area.  The cause is a lack of retainment of an object which causes early deallocation and then is overwritten.  At which time (which may be delayed), the pointer will point to garbage whose dereference (class examination) causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS to be thrown.  This error canNot be caught using @try.  There is an assumption here that the stack itself is corrupt causing continuation to be impossible (although such is most likely not the case), which will throw the debugger for a spin, whose current state output is already lacking in many areas.  It is like uncontrollable anarchy when the CPU resets important registers and performs a long jump.

consider Automatic Reference Counting.  In you are already there, consider that delegate-like properties are not retained by the host object.  Any property which could logically contain self will not retain any value stored in it.  ARC will not help you there.

in your case:  defaultQueue is probably good.  lPayment has probably been deallocated.

Comment: Hi carmin, thanks for your reply. The app is iOS6 ARC only, and I think you might be spot on with the lPayment being deallocated. Could it be because it has already been called once from the MenuView and then it is deallocated when the GameView tries to call it?
How can I prevent lPayment from deallocating, or reload it in the shop?

Comment: I assume that addPayment: is adding lPayment to a strong NS collection of some sort which will retain lPayment and the collection.  +defaultQueue is easily retained with a strong static.  You may be loosing self.  Observers areNot retained.  It is hard to tell from this short section of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to trace the problem  at first enabling  NSZombie . In case of EXC_BAD_Access Problem some time it(NSZombie ) becomes more useful to trace deallocated object than simple guessing where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I get a "message sent to deallocated instance" from the lPayment, my problem is that I don't know how to retain it or why it has been deallocated

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the information provided, but it could be the following: Your statement

```
SKPayment *lPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[mPriceArray objectAtIndex:lTag]];
```

instantiates an SKPayment object, and hands it over to the current autorelease pool. If this pool does not exist (this might be the case if the code runs in a separate thread for which no autorelease pool has been set up explicitly), the object is released immediately again, and your statement

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:lPayment];
```

accesses invalid memory.

Comment: Thanks @Reinhard, but how could I set up an autorelease pool to these objects so I can avoid this? It runs in a background tread while the main tread displays a animated activity indicator.

Comment: Hi CCDEC, thats easy: Just enclose your statements in an     @autoreleasepool {...} block!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: Every thread should set up an autorelease pool as early as possible, i.e. it should contain more or less the whole thread, see <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html>